# How can I create a non-modifiable class Flutter

Tags: flutter, oop, object, dart

I need to create a class called `GeneralAppAndDeviceDetails` which has the following fields:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class GeneralAppAndDeviceDetails {
  final bool isDarkModeEnabled;
  final double deviceWidth;
  final double deviceHeight;
  final Color primaryColor;
  final Color secondaryColor;
}
```

It basically stores general device and app information at the start of the program so that I don't need to create a new instance of `Theme` or `MediaQuery` class whenever I want to access these details.

The problem I'm facing is that how can I write this class so that after the fields' values are assigned, They will be unmodifiable? (so that nothing can change the field values)

(I tried to create a singleton class but I need to pass the values to the constructor and by using factory and private constructor, A user can create new classes with different parameters passed to the factory.)

The thing I need is to have static fields that can receive a value once and become unmodifiable after that. How can I achieve something similar?

Thank you

**Update:**

I wrote the class as below:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class GeneralAppAndDeviceDetails {
  final bool isDarkModeEnabled;
  final double deviceWidth;
  final double deviceHeight;
  final Color primaryColor;
  final Color secondaryColor;
  static bool _isAlreadyCreated = false;
  static GeneralAppAndDeviceDetails _instance;

  factory GeneralAppAndDeviceDetails(bool isDarkModeEnabled, double deviceWidth,
      double deviceHeight, Color primaryColor, Color secondaryColor) {
    if (_isAlreadyCreated == false) {
      _isAlreadyCreated = true;
      _instance = GeneralAppAndDeviceDetails._(isDarkModeEnabled, deviceWidth,
          deviceHeight, primaryColor, secondaryColor);
    }
    return _instance;
  }
  const GeneralAppAndDeviceDetails._(this.isDarkModeEnabled, this.deviceWidth,
      this.deviceHeight, this.primaryColor, this.secondaryColor);
}
```

I use a flag to check if an instance was created before or not in here and with this code, a similar instance will be returned every time but is it the best way to achieve this?

Comment: can you specify exactly what should be unmodifiable and when. should each instance of the class be constructed with potentially different values but field values should not change after construction -> constructor with final field values. should there only be ever 1 instance of this class -> singleton. are there different points in time, when the fields are assigned, but they should be final -> i guess you would need booleans to track the individual fields or a similar solution.

Comment: I need to access the fields data throughout the app so instead of creating global variables, I decided to create a class. These field values shouldn't change once they receive a value (because deviceWidth for example cannot change). For that reason, I need to make the class fields unmodifiable. I don't want to create different instance throughout the app so I need something like a singleton and the accepted answer is exactly what I need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your singleton class

```
class Test{
  
  final String str;
  
  static Test _singleton;
  Test._internal({this.str});
  factory Test(String str) {
    return _singleton ??= Test._internal(
    str: str
    );
  }
  
}
```

example code for you to try and test

```
void main() {
  Test obj = Test('ABC');
  print(obj.str);
  Test obj1 = Test('XYZ');
  print(obj1.str);
}

class Test{
  
  final String str;
  
  static Test _singleton;
  Test._internal({this.str});
  factory Test(String str) {
    return _singleton ??= Test._internal(
    str: str
    );
  }
  
}
```

try running this in [dartpad](https://dartpad.dev/) for better understanding

Answer (score 1):

you can make the class as singleton and then make these fields as private, accessible only through getters and setters, inside the setter you can check and discard the new value if there is already some value assigned to the field.

Comment: I updated the question. Please let me know what you think.

Comment: looks good, once created it will always return the same instance and the values can only be modified first time